# when I've tried to run my flutter in vs code it gave this error in debug console

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Could not find an option with short name "-n".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.
Exited (64)

Comment: please run flutter clean and if you use iOS device to run your app make sure you use pod install manually

Comment: I did it and it  and also did flutter pub cache repair 
still don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like some unexpected arguments are being passed to `flutter` when you try to run. These could come from a few different places:

- Check if you have a `.vscode/launch.json` file, and whether you have anything unexpected in the `args`
- Check the "Flutter Additional Args" and other similar settings in VS Code

To find out exactly what command VS Code is trying to run:

- Run the **Dart: Capture Debugging Logs** command from the command palette
- Try to run the app to generate the error
- Click **Cancel** on the logging notification to stop logging and open the log file
- Search the log file for "Spawning" and it should show the full command VS Code is trying to run

Comment: Thank you very much